# If 'pre' is previous, 'post' is after, and 'peri' is current, what is "initiation"?

Tags: time, prefixes

In chronology: pre-event, ?-event, peri-event, post-event
Maybe "ini-event" from Latin "initium"?

Comment: It's not clear how you wan t to use this word. _Initiation_ is indeed derived from _initium_, but what has that to do with the prefixes _pre_  and _post_?

Comment: Are you looking for the *start* of the event? If it's a football game, that's the *kickoff*.

Comment: Surely any initiation happens before the event, so is pre-event?

Comment: By the way, *peri-* doesn't really work. True, Wiktionary lists [*perievent*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/peri-#English), but no other dictionary does. In listed entries in the OED, for example, *peri-* always has a spatial meaning, either 'the closest point' (*pergee, perihelion*) or 'around the point' (*periarterial, periocular*).

Comment: I think it is reasonably clear what the OP is asking. The prefixes *pre-* and *post-* are very productive in combining with root words signifying events to produce words that denote the time before the event and after the event, respectively. So we have *pregame* and *postgame*, *prepublication* and *postpublication*, etc. Some roots may work with just one of them, or with neither. The OP is asking if there is a prefix denoting the time at the very start of an event. If this prefix is *x*, then *x-game* might be the kickoff, *x-wedding*  might be the very beginning of the ceremony, etc.

Comment: I suspect there isn't such a prefix, but it's a good question.

Comment: If you could describe a little more how this will be used, that would help. There isn't a strict order of temporal prefixes in English, and I can think of nothing that works with "event." The closest I can think of is is *proto-*, but in many situations I wouldn't think of *pre-event* and *proto-event* that differently, and outside an academic context I'd boggle at *peri-event* (is that like *peritext*?).

Comment: Thank you for the answers this is a great forum! I try to be more precise: I want to make use of the word "attending" to describe a certain behaviour of a person and the inner processes involved. Different processes take place before, while and after the "attending". Yet other ones in the very moment of the starting point of the goal-seeking-behaviour, in the moment of the ?-attending. In football, instead of "kickoff", the prefix would be ?-game, describing the moment between before the game and the time while the game is taking place.

Comment: A suffix? Event-initial?

Comment: Start- or first-?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a simple affix that has this meaning. When one wants to form a word for this, it's common to use the compound prefix "start-of-". So one might say

> The start-of-game activities in a foodball game are the coin toss and kickoff.

Comment: Or if you're happy with a suffix, "game-start" or "game-starting".

Comment: @StuartF "game-starting" sounds like something that causes the game to start, not something that happens at the start. "game-start" may be a possibility, but it doesn't sound natural to me.